# how to detect if file is in process in java?

Tags: java, file

I want to list files from my disk to a `BlockingQueue` and threads will process them.  In midway, if files on disk get updated then queue will also refresh.  Is there any way to find if file is in process by thread and need not to be added in queue again?

Comment: I could not understand your question.   I think you need to break it up into at least four sentences.

Comment: "..if files on disk get updated.." - so you want to know if files were updated externally and NOT by your threads?

Comment: yes like if files are added to directory or any file is updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to idnetify the process which have a file open you can use

- Linux - fuser http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser
- Windows - to list files open locally http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-find-out-which-windows-process-using-file.htm remotely http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897552

Found just now using google.

---

You could do

```
Set<File> queued = ...
Queue<File> toProcess = 


// add to the queue if its a new entry.
if(queued.add(file)) 
    toProcess.add(file);
```

Comment: does this code execute "..if files on disk get updated.." check?

Comment: You need to do this with the WatchService in Java 7 or by navigating the directories repeatedly to find the differences.

Comment: will WatchService tell you if the source of the change was RamIndani's thread or not?

Comment: i think only one way can give complete solution that is any how detecting if any file is in process of read and working on it can anyone suggest me how i can detect if file is in read process

Comment: how can we detect which thread or any thread is reading on any file or more correctly on text file

Comment: If you want ot detect if a file is being read by the same process you can maintain a list of file you are reading.  However if you want to detect if any process is reading the file you need to use a system command which will give you that information.

Comment: ok thanks Peter do you have any idea about system command that can be used ?

Comment: That depends on your operating system. Do you have windows or linux or solaris?

Comment: i am on windows will openfiles command help i don't have administrative access.

Comment: @RamIndani I would imagine you need administrator rights to see what other users are doing. Of course, its generally a better idea to design your application so it doesn't need to know if another process is using a file.

Comment: @peter i don't want another data structure to be maintained for storing files which i have processed or processing so i will delete after processing file but while reading if program will update my queue for so not to have same files twice i  want to compare if any file is already in process of reading not writing

Comment: When not have the reading process delete the file?  If the file exists, it is being read, is it doesn't exist, its not being read.

Comment: when reading will be over i will delete the file through reading program but if file is in process of reading at that time i don't want it to get listed.

Comment: Perhaps you could list in your question the stages the file goes through. before processing, during processing and after processing when when you want to avoid adding to a queue.

Comment: only while processing i don't want them to get again in queue